# Why triplet-triplet annihilation requires less power than two-photon absorption?

Tags: photons

Both two-photon absorption upconversion (TPA-UC) and triplet-triplet annihilation upconversion (TTA-UC) have quadratic dependence on incident light intensity ([ref](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/2016/CP/C5CP07296D)):

- TPA requires two simultaneous photons.
- TTA requires two molecules to be in excited triplet state.

Following Beer-Lambert law, $\frac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}x}=-\alpha I -\beta I^2$, this suggests that the two phenomena will be observed only at high intensities.

Then why TPA-UC requires >100 MW cm<sup>-2</sup> pumping power, while TTA-UC requires <100 mW cm<sup>-2</sup> only?

Comment: How long do those molecules stay in their excited state? If they can stay they for a very long time, you don't need a whole lot of power to get the system in the proper excited state. Did you look at the details before asking?

Comment: @CuriousOne The lifetime! That's exactly what I was missing. Thanks!